# WPF Binding from System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth with a Converter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm trying to bind System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth to a ColumnDefinition's (From within a 'Grid') Width property, and using a converter to convert the 'PrimaryScreenWidth' into a 'GridLength'.  But it never gets inside the 'convert' code.

Here's my XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
   <local:ScreenWidthToLeftBarWidth x:Key="leftBarConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
<ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=System.Windows.SystemParameters, Path=PrimaryScreenWidth, Converter={StaticResource leftBarConverter}}"/>
```

Here's my CodeBehind for the converter (leaving out the 'ConvertBack' method:

```
public class ScreenWidthToLeftBarWidth : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            double aValue = (double)value;
            GridLength newWidth = new GridLength(aValue);
            return (newWidth);
        }
    }
```

Now, I've been able to bind successfully in a slightly different scenario of using a 'Button' objects Width and running it through a converter, So I'm thinking the problem is with how I'm trying to bind from the "ElementName=System.Windows.SystemParameters".  Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ElementName` is for other elements in XAML; for this you will need something like [`x:Static`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742135.aspx), e.g.

```
Width="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth},
                Converter=...}"
```

Comment: I'd like it to be dynamic (there could be change notifications if the user changes their screen resolution, right?).  Also, I need a converter to change the value as it dynamically changes.  Any ideas on an alternate solution?

Comment: @RuneStar: You can use it in a binding with `Source` (see edit), to get change notifications you need to subscribe to some event (perhaps at the system level, i don't know) and then update the binding (e.g via the `BindingExpression.UpdateTarget`).