# Automatic resize of semi-fixed-sized WPF windows using Converters while listening to resolution change

Tags: c#, wpf, resolution

I'm currently creating a `css media`/`Android layout`-like behavior in WPF. Basically, I have resolution categories based on three values for screen width: 800px, 1280px, and 1920px.

There are three corresponding resource dictionaries that contain `Int32` values with keys for the UI elements. A sample entry is:

```
<sys:Int32 x:Key="initial_screen_width">1600</sys:Int32>
```

My `IConverter` simply checks the screen resolution level (the one based on screen width) and returns the key in the dictionary with the corresponding resolution:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    int dimension = 0;
    object value2 = value;
    string resourceId = (string)parameter;

    if(resourceId is string)
    {
        dimension = GetDimension(resourceId, GetResolutionLevel());
    }

    return dimension;
}
```

Lastly, I simply bind the `UserControl` attributes with the converter:

```
<UserControl
...
Height="{Binding Converter={StaticResource LayoutDimensionConverter}, ConverterParameter=initial_screen_height}"
...
>
```

It work perfectly fine-- the corresponding dimensions are returned. However, I can't seem to find a way to handle resolution change (updating the UI to adjust again). I found some links regarding the use of UpdateTarget

- [WPF Force rebind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957522/wpf-force-rebind)
- [WPF Binding from System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth with a Converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9961212/wpf-binding-from-system-windows-systemparameters-primaryscreenwidth-with-a-conve/9961247#9961247)

so I tried using the system parameters as static variables, but the resolution change is not detected. Are there ways to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was done using [SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.displaysettingschanged(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
        public SomeView()
        {
            SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged += SystemEvents_DisplaySettingsChanged;
        }

        private void SystemEvents_DisplaySettingsChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Refreshes UI
            var dataContext = DataContext;
            DataContext = null;
            DataContext = dataContext;
        }
```

Whenever the screen resolution is changed, the `DataContext` is reset and all the value converters are fired again.